# Spliting data in a db2 table using function

Tags: db2, db2-luw, stored-functions

I'm trying to select data using below sql and created the following function to split the data but I get SQL0440n error.

Comment: Db2 has no `BOOL` data type, and type casting syntax you are using is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The error "SQL0440n" simply means that a function (aka routine) in your SQL statement has not been found.

```
SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "<routine-name>" of type
      "<routine-type>" having compatible arguments was found.
```

If it is a user defined function, you will need to qualify it with a schema name when you use it, or alter your `CURRENT PATH` to let Db2 find the function by looking in a given set of schemas.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001014.html

If you still get the same error, check that the data-types of the input values to the function match, or are implicitly castable to the data-types in your function parameters